# position of modalpopupextender changes after onclick

Tags: c#, ajax

I have a modalpopupextender and have set the X and Y positions. The control first appears correctly but after clicking the "ok" button the position of the control changes.

Any ideas appreciated. Here is my code:

```
<ModalPopupExtender ID="ajax_PopUp" runat="server" 
            CancelControlID="btn_Cancel" OkControlID="btn_Send" 
            PopupControlID="panel_popup" TargetControlID="btn_ContactUser" 
            onokscript="__doPostBack('btn_Send','')" X="100" Y="100">
</asp:ModalPopupExtender>
```

Comment: @user554134 Normally, a postback would cause such issues if you defined your ModalPopupExtender dynamically, but you did not..Hmmmm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why this is happening but have a workaround in place.

In the ok button simply redirect to the same page, eg. response.redirect("pageyouwereon");

Then the control aspects seem to get set again.

Any other ideas are welcome!